# Equation of state for matter, radiation and vacuum in Roberston-Walker Metric

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion

In GR, when we write the covariant form of the energy-momentum conservation, $\nabla_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu} = 0$. From which we get the equation for the energy density,
$$\rho'(t) / \rho = -3(1+w)(a'(t) / a)$$
with the defintion that $p = w\rho$ and then solving this for three different values of $w = -1, 0, 1/3$, we get get different relations between pressure and energy density for matter, radiation and vacuum.

$p_{m} = 0$, $p_{r} = \frac{\rho_{r}}{3}$, and $p_{vacuum} = -\rho_{vacuum}$.

I am not sure how we got the values of $w$ for radiation, matter and lambda?

Kindly help me to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

In relativity, matter is a set of cold non-relativistic particles which behave like dust. There is essentially no pressure: $p_m = 0$. Stars and galaxies are considered matter because the pressure is negligible relative to the energy associated to the mass of these bodies.

Radiation (a.k.a. photon gas) is considered a perfect fluid. In an isotropic universe, the energy-momentum tensor for a perfect fluid (in its rest frame) and its trace are

$$T^\alpha_\beta = \text{diag}(-\rho, p, p, p) \\
\Rightarrow T = T^\alpha_\alpha = -\rho + 3p $$

But energy-momentum tensor for electromagnetism and its trace are

$$T^{\alpha\beta} = F^{\alpha\mu}F^\beta_\mu - \frac{1}{4}g^{\alpha\beta}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} \\
\Rightarrow T = T^\alpha_\alpha = 0$$

Equating the two expressions for the trace, we find $p_r = \frac{1}{3}\rho_r$.

For vacuum energy, the cosmological constant is viewed simply as another contribution to the energy-momentum tensor.

$$T_{(\Lambda)}^{\alpha\beta} = \frac{-\Lambda}{8\pi}g^{\alpha\beta}$$

as can be seen by rearranging the Einstein field equations. We assume vacuum energy also takes the form of a perfect fluid,

$$T^\alpha_{(\Lambda)\beta} = \frac{-\Lambda}{8\pi}\text{diag}(1, 1, 1, 1) = \text{diag}(-\rho, p, p, p)$$

So $\rho_\Lambda = \frac{\Lambda}{8\pi}$ and $p_\Lambda = -\rho_\Lambda$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So in short, the values of w comes from relating the stress-energy tensor of GR with the stress-energy tensors of different components to get the equation of state?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Yes. To be a little more specific, I’m relating the stress-energy tensor of a perfect fluid to the stress-energy tensor associated to dust, radiation, or vacuum energy.

Comment: I don't follow for the cosmological constant case. When we take the trace on both the sides, we get -(lambda) / (2pi) = -(rho) + 3p. From this, how can we conclude that the energy density is (lambda/8pi) and p(lambda) = -rho(lambda)?

Comment: We don’t take the trace for the cosmological constant case. Instead we compare the components of the tensor on both sides of the equation. For example, the first diagonal on the left, $-\Lambda/8\pi$, equals the first diagonal on the right, $-\rho$ and so on…

Comment: Ok thanks makes sense now.